# Encodings in ConfigParser (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, encoding, utf-8, configparser

Python 3.1.3
What I need is to read dictionary from cp1251-file using ConfigParser.
My example:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.optionxform = str
config.read("file.cfg")
DataStrings = config.items("DATA")
DataBase = dict()
for Dstr in DataStrings:
    str1 = Dstr[0]
    str2 = Dstr[1]
DataBase[str1] = str2
```

After that I'm trying to replace some words in some UTF-8 files according dictionary. But sometimes it doesn't works (for example, with symbols of "new line-carriage return").
My file in UTF-8 and configuration file (dictionary) in CP1251. Seems like trouble, I have to decode config into UTF-8.
I've tryed this:

```
str1 = Dstr[0].encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8-sig')
```

But error `"'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0"` appeared.
If I use `.decode('','ignore')` - I just lose almost all config file.
What should I do?

Comment: `config.read("file.cfg", encoding="cp1251")`

Comment: Sounds good, doesn't work. Already tryed. Since Python3.x there are no "encoding" attribute. Encoding is inherited from .open() default setting.

Comment: What do attributes have to do with anything? `ConfigParser.read `has had an `encoding` keyword argument at least since [python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read). I hope you are not using an older version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.1 is in the no-mans-land of Python versions. Ideally you'd upgrade to Python 3.5, which would let you do `config.read("file.cfg", encoding="cp1251")`

If you must stay on 3.1x, you can use the `ConfigParser.readfp()` method to read from a previously opened file using the correct encoding:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.optionxform = str
config_file = open("file.cfg", encoding="cp1251")
config.readfp(config_file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really